# Valleytronics and time reversal symmetry

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, time-reversal-symmetry

I am trying to understand the valleytronics in TMDC. I have searched quite a large number of research articles but they just write the valleytronics is due to time-reversal symmetry. Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In monolayer TMDs, the inversion symmetry is broken, which results in a non-zero Berry curvature of the electron bands in the vicinity of the K and K' valleys in the Brillouin zone. In addition, these compounds have strong spin-orbit coupling which results in the spin-splitting of the valence bands (and to a much lesser extent in the CB). Time reversal symmetry requires that this splitting at the two valleys must be opposite, i.e spin-up band has higher energy at one valley whereas the spin-down band has higher energy at the other valley.

This results in a coupling of the spin and valley degrees of freedom, allowing us to excite carriers of different spins and from different valleys by controlling the frequency and polarization of the probing optical fields -> Valleytronics!

Also, note that such an optical control of the valley degree of freedom is difficult in graphene due to the absence of strong spin-orbit coupling.

This paper is a good reference: D. Xiao, G.-B. Liu, W. Feng, X. Xu, and W. Yao, "Coupled Spin and Valley Physics in Monolayers of $\rm MoS_2$ and Other Group-VI Dichalcogenides", [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **108**, 196802 (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.196802).